# Java - How to see the definition of size() method in List interface?

Tags: java, collections, interface, size

In the below code, how does the `size()` method gets the value? where is the definition or control flow?

As `List` is the interface, it should not contain the definition of `size()` method. But in the below code I am able to use the `size()` method from interface without actually implementing it.

```
 List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
 String[] linkTexts = new String[linkElements.size()];
```

Comment: I don't get this question... do you purport to have implemented the `findElements` method, returning a `List` instance which does not implement `size()`??

Comment: what does `driver.findElements(` returns?

Comment: `linkElements` is an instance of `List`, this basically means it's a concrete implementation which, at the very minimum, guarantees that it honours the contract established by the interface `List`. So you're not call the interfaces `size` method, you calling the implementations (which is hidden from you in this case)

Answer (score 3):

The `size()` method is implemented (directly or indirectly) by any class that implements the `List` interface. Your `List<WebElement>` variable holds a reference to an instance of some class that implements `List<WebElement>`, and therefore contains an implementation of the `size()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I your code

```
List linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

which returns

```
IList<IWebElement>
```

object which has implementation for `size()` method.